# When to use different forms of the similar looking uncertainity equations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I usually find two different forms of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle equations as in follows:

1. $$ \Delta x \cdot \Delta p \ge h$$
2. $$ \Delta x \cdot \Delta p \ge (\frac{h}{2\pi})$$

Some text books have used the first one and the others have used the second one. How is dividing Planck's constant by $2\pi$ going to make the equation different? Under what conditions should one use the first equation and under what conditions one should use the second one?

Comment: Which exact textbooks? Which pages?

Comment: @Qmechanic Some Indian textbooks

Answer (score 1):

It's all about orders of magnitude. Heisenberg's uncertainity principal is really given by: $$\Delta x \Delta p \geq \frac{h}{4\pi}=\frac{\hbar}{2}$$ Where $\hbar=\frac{h}{2\pi}$. But sometimes the right hand side is replaced by $h$ or $\hbar$, this is simply an approximation, just to make our lives easier. So formally you should always use $\Delta x \Delta p \geq \frac{h}{4\pi}$ but if it is easier and you don't think $\Delta x \Delta p$ is going to be near $\frac{h}{4\pi}$ then you can change the RHS to something of roughly the same order of magnitude such as $h$ or $\hbar$.